# AngularJS, add row in table from bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabular

I have made a table that pulls the content from my app.js, I made a bootstrap modal where you can put your information in so that it will show up on the table.

The problem is, it's not doing anything, and I can't see where my problem is.

HTML where the information goes in:

```
    <!-- Email -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input ng-model="newUser.email" type="email" placeholder="E-Mail" required="">
    </div>
    <!-- Name -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input ng-model="newUser.name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required="">
    </div>
```

And this is the angular code which should push it into the table

```
  // Add User
  $scope.newUser = new Object();
  $scope.addUser = function() {
    if ($scope.newUser.email != undefined && $scope.newUser.name != undefined) {
      $scope.table.push($scope.newPatient);
      $scope.newUser = new Object();
    }
  }
```

---

Here's the [**codepen link**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZKVJm) with all the other code of the table

Answer (score 0):

Your modal dialog is out of scope of your controller. Look at HTML:

```
<div class="container ng-scope" ng-app="tableApp" ng-controller="mainController">
.....
</div>

<div id="add" class="modal fade in" role="dialog" style="display: block; padding-right: 17px;">
....
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have put them into the same folder, now it adds the row but not the text, just a blank row. What could be the problem?

Comment: @ekclone Could you please provide me with updated codepen link?

Comment: You trying to add $scope.newPatient but actual you have $scope.newUser

Comment: Wow thanks, I forgot to rename it after I changed the text. Thanks a lot! One last question, could you tell me how could I close the modal after submitting?

Comment: Add data-dismiss="modal" to your "Register" button